# Need an approach to get the record id from a table with hierarchy data

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I need some help in getting a record id from a table. Basically I'm working on project where the folders and files of a particular path are stored in database.

It includes a desktop and windows service applications and I'm using a SDF file for database and handling data operations using ADO.NET using C#

This is my folders table
[image]

As you can see, its a hierarchy table and FolderId is an identity column.

Now suppose my data is as

[image: data]

And I have a path as "E:\Books\WCF\Examples.pdf". Now how can I get the FolderId of "Examples.pdf" file from above table.

I came up with following approaches

**Approach 1:**
To get all the records from Folders table which match with the folder name as "WCF" along with their complete hierarchy by writing a recursive method. So I will get following data
[image]

Now in my code, I will be comparing this hierarchy column with above folder path of the pdf to get the FolderId.

**Approach 2:**
Taking each and every folder from the pdf path, I will generate dynamic query which looks something like this

```
select FolderId from Folders where Name='WCF' and
ParentFolderId in (select FolderId from Folders where Name='Books' and
ParentFolderId in (select FolderId from Folders where Name='E:'))
```

Based on my two approaches, which one should I prefer. Performance is a crucial factor and the Folders table may have more than a million records. Feel free to suggest any better approach.

Comment: Without going into "why you need it"... Recursive method. All the matching should be done on FolderId, not the name. This kind of dynamic Sql will eventually lead you into trouble.

Comment: Split the path into directories in C# and pass the result as a table-valued parameter to SQL Server. (See System.IO.Path.) A common table expression (CTE) can perform the matching one level at a time and return the result.

Comment: @T.S. As I mentioned in the beginning, this app deals with files and folders. I'm using a FileSystemWatcher to do this. So in this process, I will get the entire path of file created/deleted/renamed and I need the respective FolderId to save it into database so it will be easy for tracking

Comment: @HABO, I did not get you properly, how can we pass a table-value parameter and use a CTE in a SDF file?

Comment: Ah, not SQL Server. SQL Server CE doesn't support one or two useful features like CTEs, stored procedures, ... . Perhaps the question should be retagged. Unless you really have SQL Server available and there is a way to access a CE database, e.g. as a Linked Server or using OPENROWSET ... .

Comment: If performance is really crucial, as you say, throw that design away and store the filename, ID and path in three fields.   It will be magnitudes faster than doing self joins.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name50
(ID INT, Name  nvarchar(100), ParentID INT)
GO

INSERT INTO Table_Name50(ID, Name,ParentID)
VALUES
( 1 ,N'E:\',NULL),
( 2, N'Books',  1),
( 3, N'History', 2),
( 4, N'Biology', 2),
( 5, N'Vidoes',   1)
GO
```

**Query**

to pull the full path for a given ID

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 3

;with CompleteData
as
(
    Select ID,  ParentId from Table_Name50
    UNION
    Select Child.ParentID Id, Parent.ParentID ParentId From Table_Name50   Child
        Left Outer Join Table_Name50 Parent
            on Child.ParentID = parent.ID
    WHERE
        parent.ParentID IS NULL

),
ChildHierarchyData(ID,ParentID, Level)
as
(
    Select ID,ParentID, 0 as Level from CompleteData Where ID = @ID --<-- Your Parameter
    union all
    Select CompleteData.ID, CompleteData.ParentID, ChildHierarchyData.Level +1 from CompleteData 
        INNER Join ChildHierarchyData
            on ChildHierarchyData.ParentID = CompleteData.ID
),
Concatinated(result)
as
(
    Select Cast((select Cast(Name  as nvarchar) + '\' [data()] 
    from ChildHierarchyData CD INNER JOIN  Table_Name50 tbl
    ON CD.ID = tbl.ID
    Order By Level Desc 
    FOR XML Path('')) as Nvarchar(max))
)
select Left(result, len(result)-1) as Result from Concatinated
```

**Result**

```
E:\\ Books\ History
```